# How can I create an alias that passes additional arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, arguments

I have an executable that I use often:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/executable argv[1] argv[2] argv[3]
```

I know that I can set an alias for the executable:

```
alias myexecutable = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/executable'
```

and then call it

```
myexecutable argv[1] argv[2] argv[3]
```

However, I'd like to call it like this

```
myexecutable argv[1]
```

because the first argument is the only one that ever changes. The second and third one should always be passed as the same every time.

Comment: Aliases can't have arguments, you need a function

Comment: And [How to make the argument as optional in bash function?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/522267/how-to-make-the-argument-as-optional-in-bash-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliases don't handle arguments. Define a function:

```
myfunc () {
    /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/executable "$1" fixed-argv2 fixed-argv3
}
```